# How to ignore yield in html?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, yield

I created an html page but I do not want the header and footer to show. How would I do this?

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">  
        <%= render "layouts/header" %>
        <div id="inside"><%= yield %></div>
        <%= render "layouts/footer" %>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "render :layout => false" to your controller, like this:

```
class HomeController < AppliationController
  def index
    render :layout => false
  end
end
```

See this guide for more information on layouts/rendering: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution: Use the `content_for` helper

With the utmost respect, the accepted answer ignores your layout.

Suppose for example you want the header/footer to be displayed on some pages, but not others. How can you manage this with the [`content_for` helper](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for).

```
# layouts/application.html.erb
<% if content_for?(:header) %>     
  <%= yield(:header) %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<% end %>
```

#### Benefits

- For the pages where you want to ignore the header/footer, simply render nothing in your `content_for` block.
- For the pages where you want the default implementation, then skip the `content_for` entirely. Or you can do it vice versa, by inverting the if statement.
- You get to keep your layout.